# get ajax posted Data From Request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to get these ajax posted data from request body ?

```
search=title&searchType=department+1&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: you mean getting querystring parameters in  body?

Comment: yes i want to get these parameters like querystring

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter that you need to get from the body.

```
Public ActionResult ([FromBody] string param1)
{
    return View();
}
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get QueryString paramaters as arguments in your Controller:

```
Public ActionResult Index(string search, string searchType,string XRequestedWith)
{
    return View();
}
```

Of course this way your paramater can not have dashes like `X-Requested-With`

You can also use `Request.QueryString` to get QueryString. This way you won't have the restriction above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get those ajax posted data from request body the first instruction is not to put those values in query string put those values in form body.Better it would be if you create a modal and use those property to pass in ajax.

Now you would fetch those value in action method like

```
Public ActionResult YourMethodName([FromBody]YourModel objYourModel)
{
   // use objYourModel to fetch your values
   return View();
}
```